# how to fully setup jenkins nodes using CasC (configuration as code)?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using [this example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/README.md) to create my own Jenkins server using configuration as code. So far I've managed to create a permanent node using the config provided in the example, but I don't see any explanations on how to take this to the next level.

What I'm looking for is a node that will be launched using `ssh`. I've tried to replace the `jnlp` with `ssh` but failed. I don't see any documentation on how to do this...

This is my config file so far:

```yaml
jenkins:
  securityRealm:
    local:
      allowsSignup: false
      users:
       - id: ${JENKINS_ADMIN_ID}
         password: ${JENKINS_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
  authorizationStrategy:
    globalMatrix:
      permissions:
        - "Overall/Administer:admin"
        - "Overall/Read:authenticated"
  nodes:
    - permanent:
        name: "bla"
        remoteFS: "/tmp/bla"
        numExecutors: 3
        nodeDescription: "description..."
        labelString: "label1 label2"
        launcher:
          ssh:
            host: "192.168.21.128"
            port: "22"
            sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy: "nonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy"
unclassified:
  location:
      url: http://localhost:80/
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find anything in documentation, but I did find something in the issues on their [github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/issues/1915).

Using this, I managed to create an SSH agent.

This is not a full answer, as this only covers a few things I need, but it does give me something to work with

Comment: It looks like the documentation has since morphed since this was posted. Have no idea how to get jenkins to talk to the agent. Any hints? How do you specify the key to use?